# Insert one MenuItem as Region in Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have module with MenuItem Control.

Module:

```
public class AboutPopupModule : IModule
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        var regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("AboutPopup", typeof(AboutMenuView));
    }
}
```

This is AboutMenuView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrismModules.AboutPopup.Views.AboutMenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <MenuItem Header="_О программе" Command="{Binding AboutPopupCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

When I paste this region into my menu in another application:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Проект">
            <MenuItem Header="Выполнить" Command="{Binding RunCommand}">
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Помощь">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="AboutPopup"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Visually it all looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBWLx.jpg

## Question

Please tell me how you can remove these huge fields left and right

Comment: Can you show `AboutMenuView` unabridged? As is, it won't even compile. Also, a `MenuItem` with a `ContentControl` inside that contains as `UserControl` containing another `MenuItem` looks overly complicated to me. Why not just add the `_О программе` `MenuItem` to the menu?

Comment: @Haukinger, certainly not compiled. I wanted the code to read better. Added full view. 
I have many applications where this menu item is needed. I don’t want in every application to climb into the VM and add the DelegateCommand and its processing

Comment: @Haukinger, maybe you have any suggestions